# Cocos2d-x onTouchMoved called when no movement is occurring

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

I'm writing a cocos2d-x 3.71 cross-platform app (ios, android, windows10) and am having trouble with my implementation of touch and hold detection **on Android only** (ios and windows work just fine).  I have tracked the reason for this down to the fact that when holding a touch down and not moving, *onTouchMoved*() is firing off constantly.  I have incorporated a work-around, but this seems like a bug and I'm  wondering if anyone has any ideas.

I recreated the problem in a minimal app based on the cocos2d-x HelloWorld example.  I simply derived a class from *cocos2d::Node* (testNode) and created it and added it as a child to the HelloWorldScene.  In testNode, I override the update function and schedule it with *scheduleUpdate*() from *onTouchBegan*().  In the update() function, I simply count time until I reach 0.25s and then disable the update with *unscheduleUpdate*().  I had another *unscheduleUpdate*() call in *onTouchMoved*() to stop counting hold time in case the touch moved.  The problem is, on Android, *onTouchMoved*() starts firing constantly while the touch is standing still.

```
testNode.h: 
#pragma once
#include "cocos2d.h"

class testNode : public cocos2d::Node
{
public:
    testNode() {}
    ~testNode() {}
    CREATE_FUNC(testNode);

    virtual bool init();
    virtual void update(float dt);

    bool onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);
    void onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);
    void onTouchEnded(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);
    void onTouchCancelled(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);

private:
    cocos2d::DrawNode* d;
    int id;
    bool touchIsDown;
    float touchTime;
    cocos2d::Label *messageLabel;
    cocos2d::Vec2 center;
};
```

testNode.cpp:

```
#include "testNode.h"
USING_NS_CC;

bool testNode::init()
{

    if (!Node::init())
    {
        return false;
    }
    setContentSize(Size(50, 50));

    Size size = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    setPosition(Vec2(size.width / 2.0f, size.height / 2.0f));
    center.x = size.width / 2.0f;
    center.y = size.height / 2.0f;

    d = DrawNode::create();
    addChild(d, 10);
    d->drawCircle(Vec2(0, 0), 50, (float)M_PI * 2, 50, false, Color4F::RED);

    auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    touchListener->setSwallowTouches(true);
    touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(testNode::onTouchBegan, this);
    touchListener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(testNode::onTouchEnded, this);
    touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(testNode::onTouchMoved, this);
    touchListener->onTouchCancelled = CC_CALLBACK_2(testNode::onTouchCancelled, this);

    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener, this);

    messageLabel = Label::createWithTTF("Hello World", "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 18);

    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
    messageLabel->setPosition(Vec2(0,0));
    addChild(messageLabel, 1);
    return true;
}

void testNode::update(float deltaTime)
{
    // When update is scheduled with scheduleUpdate(), this will increment the touchtimer
    // used for differenciating different touch actions.
    if (touchIsDown)
    {
        touchTime += deltaTime;
        if (touchTime > 0.25)
        {
            unscheduleUpdate();
        }
    }
}

bool testNode::onTouchBegan(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    Vec2 touchPoint = touch->getLocation();
    float startDistFromCenter = center.getDistance(touchPoint);
    touchTime = 0.0f;

    // Handle touch only if inside the radius of the circle
    if (startDistFromCenter <= 50)
    {
        // Track how long the touch is held without moving or releasing
        touchIsDown = true;
        scheduleUpdate();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
void testNode::onTouchMoved(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    Vec2 pos = touch->getLocation();
    log("moving...pos = %f , %f", pos.x, pos.y);
    touchIsDown = false;
    unscheduleUpdate();
}
void testNode::onTouchEnded(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    touchIsDown = false;
    unscheduleUpdate();

    log("Hold Time: %f", touchTime);
}

void testNode::onTouchCancelled(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
}
```

---

Typical output from a touch/hold event:

> 09-23 23:42:39.852: D/cocos2d-x debug info(32508):
>   startDistFromCenter: 33.753014 09-23 23:42:39.902: D/cocos2d-x debug
>   info(32508): moving...pos = 246.732849 , 126.925316 09-23
>   23:42:39.902: D/cocos2d-x debug info(32508): moving...pos = 246.732849
>   , 126.925316 09-23 23:42:39.920: D/cocos2d-x debug info(32508):
>   moving...pos = 246.732849 , 126.925316 09-23 23:42:39.935: D/cocos2d-x
>   debug info(32508): moving...pos = 246.732849 , 126.925316 09-23
>   23:42:39.969: D/cocos2d-x debug info(32508): moving...pos = 246.732849
>   , 126.925316 09-23 23:42:39.969: D/cocos2d-x debug info(32508):
>   moving...pos = 246.732849 , 126.925316 09-23 23:42:39.989: D/cocos2d-x
>   debug info(32508): moving...pos = 246.732849 , 126.925316 09-23
>   23:42:39.999: D/cocos2d-x debug info(32508): moving...pos = 246.732849
>   , 126.925316 09-23 23:42:40.027: D/cocos2d-x debug info(32508):
>   moving...pos = 246.732849 , 126.925316 09-23 23:42:40.043: D/cocos2d-x
>   debug info(32508): moving...pos = 246.732849 , 126.925316 09-23
>   23:42:40.043: D/cocos2d-x debug info(32508): Hold Time: 0.042597

As you can see, the position is **not** actually moving....what gives?

For reference, I am developing on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, cocos2d-x 3.71, and testing on Android 5.1.1 (OnePlusOne phone)

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You can start an issue in github: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x. A workaround could be calculate Dx and Dy and only do something if Dx > 0 && Dy > 0.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I already had implemented a similar fix related to checking for actual movement.  Issue has been submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and the issue is related to android lollipop. On kitkat everything is working (testing device Huawei Ascend P7 android 4.4.2):

```
09-24 11:51:25.351: D/cocos2d-x debug info(1058): Hold Time: 0.252129
09-24 11:51:27.361: D/cocos2d-x debug info(1058): Hold Time: 0.251298
09-24 11:51:28.711: D/cocos2d-x debug info(1058): Hold Time: 0.252115
09-24 11:51:30.101: D/cocos2d-x debug info(1058): Hold Time: 0.251961
```

I tried also on lollipop device (LG, but I don't remember exactly model) and it's like you said. Spam of touch moved with the same position.

As a workaround you can do like Alex G said or remember last position (remember it at touch began) and ignore events with exactly the same position.

Btw I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite and Cocos2d-x 3.8.

You should start an issue on cocos2d-x github page.

Comment: Thanks for testing this out and confirming on Lollipop vs KitKat (also confirmation that the bug still exists in 3.8).  Issue #14021  submitted on GitHub.